Advantages and disadvantages of rotated surface code
I think one of the advantages of rotated surface code is that it can express surface code with fewer physical bits. Are there any other advantages?
Also, are there any disadvantages compared to surface code?

One disadvantage of the rotated surface code is that hook errors can reduce the effective code distance if oriented the wrong way.

Thank you, I'll look into it.

But there are syndrome schedules which avoid them: https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/surface-17

Also, just alternating the order from round to round fixes them regardless of the order (d-1 instead of d/2). That works even in complex situations with corners and domain walls and such.
